# Call java class from javascript

Tags: javascript, applet

i am developing a standalone application using html and want to call method residing in a applet class from a javascript function can it be done?? if  yes how?

```
public class appletToWrite extends Applet{
public void writeFile()
{
    String asPath = this.getParameter("path"); 
    int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,asPath+ "========OverWrite existing file? ", "File already Exists!!!", 0);
}
```

and HTML as

```
<applet id=FormApplet name='FormApplet'  code='appletToWrite.class' width='384' height='28' mayscript >
                <PARAM name="path" value="Param Sent to Applet!"> </param>
                <PARAM name="data" value="Param Sent to Applet!"> </param>
                <PARAM name="overwrite" value="Param Sent to Applet!"> </param>
            </applet>
```

but still its not working, i am making the call as follows
`document.FormApplet.writeFile();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your applet name is "myApp".

Then you have this method inside it for example,

```
public void hi() {
Graphics g = getGraphics();
g.drawString("wads up", 10, 10);}
```

You can call

```
<INPUT type="button" value="call method"    
onClick = "document.appName.hi()">
```

----UPDATE----

if you wish to accept parameters in your app, you need to specify this in your applet codes:

```
String para = this.getParameter("fromPage");
```

and you can have

```
<PARAM name="fromPage" value="Param Sent to Applet!">
```

from within the applet tags

to pass it to the applet

Comment: actually m writting a file based on 2 parameters being passed to my method residing in applet, i am unable to call the method :( i have signed the jar as well

Comment: @varun Updated with parameter support

Comment: updated question, cant we dynamically set the param values using javascript?

Comment: @varun I believe you can set param values, using DOM of javascript

Comment: didnt worked that way tried it, got alternative we can simply pass the values to function..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at : http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0170.html.

Comment: checked the link provided, actually m writting a file based on 2 parameters being passed to my method residing in applet, i am unable to call the method :(